# ERROR: "Failed to remove file containing old repository connection information" when 'pmrep connect' command fails

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Trying to invoke the command line pmrep, receiving this error.

Informatica Knowledge Base is referring to the cause as:

a) Env. variable is set incorrectly - INFA_REPCNX_INFO
b) User running the command has the home directory set incorrectly

None of these two errors check out, no matter the manipulations. Since these are the only references I have found so far, decided to post here to see if anyone has extra ideas.

Environment: Linux, Korn shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you can actually write to the pmrep.cnx file.
If not, you may have busted permissions of your home directory, which is never good.

Comment: Ugh... I had 544 there somehow, added o+w and it now works.